# 'Work towards' usage

Tags: sentence-construction

I am struggling to construct a sentence, I have rearranged it so many times that it started to become meaningless in my mind so I would appreciate some help:

This is what I currently have:

> Integrity and discipline are strengths I work towards developing every day of my life.

However, I feel like there is something wrong about it. I'm just trying to say that I consider those two things (integrity and discipline) very important and I try to develop them every day.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sentence is idiomatic, although **works towards developing** is wordy cant for "try to develop" or "seek to develop".

Comment: Here's a plot of the phrase's arc:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work+towards+developing&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwork%20towards%20developing%3B%2Cc0

Comment: And here's a plot of the phrase compared to the more tried-and-true alternatives: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work+towards+developing%2Cseek+to+develop%2C+try+to+develop&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwork%20towards%20developing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseek%20to%20develop%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctry%20to%20develop%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tᴚoɯɐuo mentions, there is correct English grammar, and then there is good English *style*.  You have the grammar part, but "work towards developing" is *wordy*.  You can substitute with alternatives like "seek to develop" or "try to develop" which avoid the stylistically awkward *-ing* form.

> Integrity and discipline are traits I **work to develop** every day of my life

Aside from the basic English style stuff, the real problem here is that your sentence is *wishy-washy*.  I don't think you want to sound indecisive, as if you're *trying* to do something but possibly failing at it. When making statements of personal character, be bold:

> Integrity and discipline are traits I **develop** every day, (through ...)

Even this is somewhat juvenile, in my opinion. It's easy to claim to have moral values, but what's more interesting is to describe the ways in which you effectively demonstrate these values:

> When I was sixteen I promised my father that I would help him take care of my elderly grandparents, so, as I have done every morning since, I wake up early to cook them breakfast before I head off to school.

With this sentence I don't have to say "I have integrity and discipline".  That's obvious from the context.  It's a much more powerful yet honest way to deliver the point.